# shell script giving "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified" when trying to execute sudo command

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ubuntu

- I have a shell script which creates a user and executes another script as  that user

  ```
  sudo useradd -m devops
  sudo passwd devops
  sudo adduser devops sudo  
  su - devops -c "sh /path/to/myscript.sh"
  ```
- This script creates the user,sets the password and adds user to sudo group as expected.
- myscript.sh contains commands which uses sudo previlages. (sudo apt-get update, sudo apt-get install software-properties-common etc.). And other commands like ssh-keygen,curl and wget.
- All commands except the one's with sudo are executed correctly and producing results as excepted.
- But commands having sudo fails by giving the error **"no tty present and no askpass program specified"**
- Why does this happen in this case and how can I overcome this?
- I have seen similiar questions but will be thankful if I get a clear explanation in this context,thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to replace this:

```bash
su - devops -c "sh /path/to/myscript.sh"
```

with this:

```bash
sudo -u devops -H sh -c "sh /path/to/myscript.sh"
```

The `-c` option of `su` doesn't support interactive mode:

> `-c, --command COMMAND`    Specify a command that will be invoked by
>   the shell using its -c.
>
> The executed command will have no controlling terminal. This option
>   cannot be used to execute    interractive programs which need a
>   controlling TTY.

(`man su`)

By the way, I wouldn't use `sudo` within a script everywhere. The script might simply require `root` permissions. Within the script you might drop privileges where necessary by means of the above-mentioned `sudo` command.

Comment: Thanks, now the script works. But I didnt understand the last part of your answer. Yes many of the command needs root privilages. What is the problem with using sudo?

Comment: @user3356760, it's not quite a problem. If the "master" script is written mostly on root's behalf, then it might be better idea to omit `sudo` for root, and require the user to run the script with root permissions. Besides, `sudo` caches user's credentials for 5 minutes(if not overridden by `timeout` in `/etc/sudoers`); then the user has to enter password again. So if a process launched with `sudo` runs more than the `timeout`, the next `sudo` invocation will ask for password again.

Comment: oh. I though that the credentials would kept for a session until user exits. Thanks again.